# Android: Start Service at certain Battery Level

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I want to start an IntentService if the battery level reaches a certain value while charging.

However, I dont want to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` because i need the service only started at a certain level (e.g. 40%) and only while charging.

Another idea would be starting a service that runs as long as the phone is charged and register a receiver programmatically.
A third idea would be to periodically start a service with `AlarmManager` and check battery level.

What is the best way?

**Solution:**
I have implemented the fourth idea from answer below.

```
final int PI_REQUEST_CODE = 123456;
int pref_BatteryUpdatePeriod = 120000;  // 2 minutes

// set repeating alarm manager
Intent monitorIntent = new Intent(this, CheckBatteryReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), PI_REQUEST_CODE, monitorIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), pref_BatteryUpdatePeriod, pendingIntent);
```

and the broadcast receiver for the alarm:

```
public class CheckBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private int targetBatterylevel = 40;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // get sticky intent
    Intent batteryStatusIntent = context.getApplicationContext()
            .registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int batteryLevel = batteryStatusIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 50);

    // evaluate battery level
    if(batteryLevel >= targetBatterylevel){
        // start service to stop charging
    } else {
        // continue charging
    }       
}
}
```

Note: I had to use `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of `context` otherwise the app would crash with an exception that I can't register a receiver within a broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont want to register a BroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED in the AndroidManifest.xml because i need the service only started at a certain level (e.g. 40%) and only while charging.

That does not work anyway, as you cannot register for that broadcast in the manifest.

> Another idea would be starting a service that runs as long as the phone is charged and register a receiver programmatically.

Yuck.

> A third idea would be to periodically start a service with AlarmManager and check battery level.

A fourth idea is to use `AlarmManager`, as you suggest, but bypass the service at the outset. Just have `AlarmManager` invoke a `BroadcastReceiver`. It can check the battery level by calling `context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))` (on the `context` passed into `onReceive()`). The `Intent` returned by `registerReceiver()` will be the last broadcast of `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. If the battery level is at or below your desired threshold, then start your `IntentService`. You may need to adopt the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or `WakefulIntentService` pattern if your alarm will wake up the device. Also allow the user to choose the polling period, so they can trade off precision for better device performance.

I would go with the fourth idea.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound too bad to have a service running, reacting to `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED` as long as it doesn't do anything when you don't need it to. That is, have a check for the interesting battery level and charging state early and just exit if you have nothing to do.

If you want to complicate things, register a mini service which only has the task of starting your main service when conditions are right. However, I don't see what benefit that would have.

Comment: Yeah, good idea too but I think alarm based checking is the better way ;) Additionally I can't be sure that the service wont be killed...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");


    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```